# react-native-image-crop-picker ios gallery closes

Tags: ios, react-native, gallery

For the first time picker opens gallery - all is ok. For the second time and other next times picker opens gallery and closes it right away.
If I try use Camera - same result.
Problem on device and simulator.

NSCameraUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription, NSMicrophoneUsageDescription are added to info.plist.

No any error in xcode, simulator and logs. App doesn't crash.

react-native: 0.62.2
react-native-image-crop-picker: 0.35.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in modal, that prefers to open camera or gallery, I close modal before calling Picker- that makes issue
on iOS only, android - ok. Then I close modal after calling Picker and receiving file object - iOS works ok.
I use this issue https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1433

My final code:

```
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        cropping: true,
    })
        .then(fileObj => {
            this.setState({
                isPhotoChoiceModalOpen: false,
            });
            return uploadImage(fileObj, user);
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by adding a setTimeout of 100 ms.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
    })
      .then((image) => { ...})),100)
```

I think gallery and camera in ios uses some animation which causes this issue.
Also note that if u  are using any modal open/close operation with animation during gallery/camera open, that may also cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is an animation time that occurs when the modal is closed only on iOS, so I solved it with the code below.

```js
setTimeout(() => {

  // ▼ your code
  ImagePicker.openPicker({
    ...
　 })
  .then(image => {
   ...
   })
  .catch(err => console.error(err.message))
  // ▲ your code

}, 1000);
```

Wrapped in `setTimeout` and solved it